# How to correctly split MNIST dataset into training and validation set?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, training-data

I have a really simple code that takes the training data from MNIST and then chooses the last 10,000 examples as validation set, then deletes the last 10,000 examples from the training set.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
(X_train, Y_train)= tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

X_valid = X_train[-10000:]
Y_valid = Y_train[-10000:]

X_train = X_train[0:40000]
Y_train = Y_train[0:40000]
```

However, this is very dumb in my opinion and I would like to make the data splitting procedure more sophisticated in the following ways:

1. I should specify which percentage of the data I want as validation set, instead of just taking the last whatever samples
2. I need a way to make sure that the data is balanced after I partition it into training and validation. Grabbing a portion could cause a the training examples associated with some digits to be very few.

Surprisingly I went through almost every Tensorflow tutorial and none of them does any validation (except for https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch, which uses the same dumb data splitting methodology as above). Most examples just directly splits the data into train and test which we almost never do in real life.

Could someone please advise?

Comment: You are not using the load_data function correctly, it returns four tuples, with the test set already split, see the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy But I don't want a test set

Comment: The load_data function always returns the test set, you need to capture it using a tuple and the you can ignore it.

Answer (score 4):

The `keras.datasets.mnist` dataset loads the dataset by [Yann LeCun](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)   ([Refer Doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data))

The dataset is setup in such a way that it contains 60,000 training data and 10,000 testing data.

Since the `load_data()` just returns Numpy arrays, you can easily concatenate the train and test arrays into a single array, after which you can play with the new array as you like.

If you want a validation set out of the training set, then you can shuffle the training set first and then extract the validation set.

All these operations will be simple Numpy Array operations and wouldn't even require any Tensorflow functionality.